# Nautilus Accels on Debian 9/Gnome 3.22.3

Tags: debian, nautilus

When I open nautilus and right-click in a folder, there is an option "Open Terminal Here". Before updating to Debian 9, I had a Keyboard Shortcut set in the file `~/.config/nautilus/accels`, where I uncommented the line

`(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal" "F12")`

After updating, it doesn't work. The menu item is still there on right-click in nautilus but the accel doesn't work anymore. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an Ubuntu 18.04 user (with GNOME 3.28.3) and this have worked wonderfully for me. Hope it does for you too :)

Since version 3.15.4 Nautilus doesn't load the accel file anymore [(Source)](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/blob/master/NEWS#L422).

Fortunatelly there's a better aproach in order to get what you want. Long explanation/useful resources can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) and also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16/696901#696901). In short:

1. Create a script called `Terminal` (yes, without a extension) inside the folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` with the following content:

   ```
   # !/bin/sh
   gnome-terminal
   ```
2. Make it executable, then close any Nautilus instance:

   ```
   chmod +x Terminal
   nautilus -q
   ```
3. Create (or edit) the `~/.config/nautilus/scripts-accels` file adding these lines:

   ```
   F4 Terminal
   ; Commented lines must have a space after the semicolon
   ; Examples of other key combinations:
   ; <Control>F12 Terminal
   ; <Alt>F12 Terminal
   ; <Shift>F12 Terminal
   ```
4. Test it! Open Nautilus, right click, and choose Scripts > Terminal. Or, use the keyboard shortcut that you've just configured :)

Comment: +1:Thank you, works for `Ubuntu 18.10 GNOME Shell 3.30.1` too.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.20. I could not use `<Alt>O` as I wanted, but `F12` worked nicely.